# Scraping facebook likes, comments and shares with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape number of likes, comments and shares with Beautiful soup and Python.
I have wrote a code, but it returns me the empty list, I do not know why:

this is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


website = "https://www.facebook.com/nike"

soup = requests.get(website).text
my_html = BeautifulSoup(soup, 'lxml')


list_of_likes = my_html.find_all('span', class_='_81hb')
print(list_of_likes)

for i in list_of_likes:
    print(i)
```

The same is with comments and likes. What should I do?

Comment: Firstly, I wouldn't expect that class to be stable. Secondly, if you look at the HTML you've downloaded, I doubt there's as much content as you expected to see.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses client side rendering...that means in the HTML document that you get and you have it stored in *soup* variable is just javascript code that actually renders the content only when you display it in browser.

Comment: You HAVE the javascript code. Problem is you need the HTML elements. The elements are rendered when you load the code in browser, so for your purpose the best way would be to use selenium webdriver https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can try use the [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver).